# Is curry ketchup just ketchup with curry powder?

Tags: spices, curry, condiments, ketchup

We use both tomato ketchup and curry ketchup as condiments in Belgium. On the curry ketchup label, amongst other ingredients is "curry (1%)".

So I tried adding curry powder to regular ketchup to see whether I could end up with curry ketchup, but I think the taste was off. The colour was close though.

I know "curry powder" is a spice mix that can differ, but is curry ketchup really just ketchup with curry powder added? Or do they mean a bit of a real curry (the dish)? Or are there other differences? Is it possible to make curry ketchup with regular ketchup?

Comment: If you want to win books, enter our competition! See http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/its-condiments-week-ask-great-questions-enter-to-win-a-prize for more information.

Comment: The dish called "curry" has many different meanings, depending on your region. "Curry" in a Thai restaurant is completely different than "curry" found in an Indian restaurant.  I have no idea what Belgian curry would be like. :)

Comment: I found a [thread on Food.com](http://www.food.com/bb/viewtopic.zsp?t=215236) talking about trying to re-create curry ketchup ... most of the recipes have black pepper and onions in them.  Also, there's a mention that letting it sit for the flavors meld may be significant (or heating the ketchup to speed the process).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suppose the Belgian "curry ketchup" is similar to the German varieties and no, they are usually not only seasoned with curry powder, but also other spices. There is no standard seasoning mix for curry ketchup, but common additional spices are ginger, black pepper, paprika, cayenne or other chili powders. I also think that some brands contain onions.

The brownisher colour of curry ketchup is mostly because of the turmeric in the curry powder, so just adding the powder to regular ketchup will get you a colour match even without the additional spices or ingredients.

Comment: I remember quite a clove cardamom flavor in curry ketchup. I'd try a curry paste too in place of powder. A nice Biryani perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

Curry Ketchup is made with a Ketchup base, but then adds Curry, vinegar, a small amount of spices like pepprika, and two little known ingredients... apples and soy sauce... if you make it to this recipe then you can get close. See the following from Hienz

Water, sugar, tomato paste (17%), vinegar, apples, modified starch, curry (2.2%) (contains mustard and celery), salt, soy sauce (water, soy beans, wheat, salt), spices, thickener (guar kernel flour, xanthan) herb extracts.

Ps make sure that the apple juice/sauce and soy sauce are minimal (as they are near the end of the ingredient list its the least used but the apple does make the difference in the sauce and the small amount of soyu brings it back from tasting too much like candy :)

Comment: What is "curry" then? The Indian dish? A spice mix?

Answer (score 1):

Not likely.

Standard curry powders are really not good if they are added to anything and left raw (some brands might not even be safe!), they tend to taste raw, unharmonic, floury, bitter then ...

Adding them while MAKING the ketchup, or adding it to the ketchup then cooking the resulting sauce, or blooming it in hot oil THEN adding it to ketchup, could all work reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

This article seems to suggest that this is the case.

http://www.thekitchn.com/ketchup-with-a-kick-add-curry-87686

Comment: Can yo summarize the contents of the article in your answer to make the answer more complete?

Comment: Certainly: curry powder + ketchup = yummy

Comment: '[Curry ketchup](http://www.amazon.com/Hela-Curry-Gewurz-Hot-Ketchup/dp/B000NY4SA6/)' is a specific condiment found in Belgium & the Netherlands.  I'd describe it as closer to shashlik sauce than to American ketchup.

Answer (score 0):

Brooklyn Delhi says their very popular Curry ketchup is 50/50 regular ketchup and tomato achaar.  https://www.instagram.com/brooklyndelhi/p/C2QN8YGPZit/

As someone who grew up with USA ketchup, I should give a little perspective, every time I tried German curry ketchup, the taste and texture made it seem to me like breakfast syrup and cloves were also ingredients, so I don't think you can replicate that just by adding curry powder to regular ketchup.

Comment: "Breakfast syrup" is likely fenugreek.